# Installation of LXD fails on Redhat 7

Tags: lxc, lxd

As there is no rpm package not a yum package, I had to install lxd from the source code. Here is the error I get:
[admin@gol05854 lxd]$ make

## Must a few times due to go get race

go get -t -v -d ./...
go get -t -v -d ./...
go get -t -v -d ./...
go install -v  ./...
gopkg.in/lxc/go-lxc.v2

## pkg-config --cflags lxc

Package lxc was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lxc.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'lxc' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
make: *** [default] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `lxc-devel` package. This is one of the requirement of lxd.